# Box2D LibGDX Body.getPosition() and Body.getWorldCenter() problems

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, body, joints

I have a problem with my game in Java with Box2D and LibGDX

I found out that when I use

body.getPosition() it is only half of that of body.getWorldCenter().

The problem here is for me that I use Joints also, which forces me into using body.getPosition().

But now my body gets drawn on the position of body.getWorldCenter().

which makes it so it looks like that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsTNl.png

Here is the source code where I create the Car Body

}

```
public static Body createCarBody(Vector2 position, float sizeX, float sizeY, float density, float friction, float restitution, float linearDamping, float angularDamping)
{

    System.out.println("position createCarBody " + position);
    Body body = Physics.createBody(createBodyDef(position, linearDamping, angularDamping));
    body.createFixture(createFixtureDefCar(createPolygonShape(sizeX, sizeY,position), density, friction, restitution));

    return body;
}

public static FixtureDef createFixtureDefCar(PolygonShape shape, float density, float friction, float restitution)
{
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = density;
    fixtureDef.friction = friction;
    fixtureDef.restitution = restitution;
    return fixtureDef;

}

public static PolygonShape createPolygonShape(float sizeX, float sizeY, Vector2 position)
{

    PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
    polygonShape.setAsBox(sizeY/2 , sizeX/2, position,0);

    System.out.println("position polygonshape " + position);

    return polygonShape;
}
```

I use the createCarBody method in my car class where it is given a Position Vector of (30,30) ( first car ) and (40,40) second car

If I print body.getWorldCenter() i get (60,60) and (80,80 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the `position` to the `Shape` if the `FixtureDef`, apply the `position` to the `Body`.

Something like this might work for you;

```
public static Body createCarBody(Vector2 position, float sizeX, float sizeY, float density, float friction, float restitution, float linearDamping, float angularDamping) {
    System.out.println("position createCarBody " + position);
    Body body = Physics.createBody(createBodyDef(position, linearDamping, angularDamping));
    body.createFixture(createFixtureDefCar(createPolygonShape(sizeX, sizeY), density, friction, restitution));
    body.setTransform(position, 0.0f); // Set the position of your body
    return body;
}

public static FixtureDef createFixtureDefCar(PolygonShape shape, float density, float friction, float restitution) {
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = density;
    fixtureDef.friction = friction;
    fixtureDef.restitution = restitution;
    return fixtureDef;
}

public static PolygonShape createPolygonShape(float sizeX, float sizeY) {
    PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
    polygonShape.setAsBox(sizeY/2 , sizeX/2); // Don't set a position here
    return polygonShape;
}
```

Comment: @chinwong Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position on the FixtureDef.

I'll assume that you already converted the units to Box2d:

```
public static Body createCarBody(Vector2 position, float sizeX, float sizeY, float density, float friction, float restitution, float linearDamping, float angularDamping){

System.out.println("position createCarBody " + position);
Body body = Physics.createBody(createBodyDef(position, linearDamping, angularDamping));
body.createFixture(createFixtureDefCar(createPolygonShape(sizeX, sizeY), density, friction, restitution, position, sizeX, sizeY));

return body; 
}

public static FixtureDef createFixtureDefCar(PolygonShape shape, float density, float friction, float restitution, Vector2 position, float sizeX, float sizeY){
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = shape;
fixtureDef.density = density;
fixtureDef.friction = friction;
fixtureDef.restitution = restitution;

//Set your position here
fixtureDef.position.set((position.x + sizeX / 2),
            (position.y + sizeY / 2));
return fixtureDef;
}
public static PolygonShape createPolygonShape(float sizeX, float sizeY){
PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
polygonShape.setAsBox(sizeX/2 , sizeY/2); 
//Don't set the position on the shape

return polygonShape;
}
```